# Update Google Directions on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a mobile app using Phonegap, JQuery Mobile and Google Maps API V3.  The mobile app will allow users to input a destination address and then using the Google Directions API, I will show them the navigation directions to arrive to their destination.

However, the application will also be marking on the map any roads closed due to construction or maintenance works.  Is there a way so that if Google Directions shows the driver to go through a particular road where there are maintenance works I change the route for him to go through a different street?  The road which will be closed will be marked by a map marker, so as such all I need to do is check if there is a marker and if so, update the route to go from a nearby road/side street.

I am quite new to this, and would be really glad if someone can point me to some tutorial or tell me how this can be done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to the specified particular road though, you might be able to get alternative route from Google Direction API.

You should specify "provideRouteAlternatives" property when the code invokes DirectionsService.route() method.
Then Google will attempt to calculate another routes.
That is only available option that I have known.

- provideRouteAlternatives property
  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRequest